# Adding records to multiple tables when only have one model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models `clients`, `client_categories` and `clients_category_merge`.
I want to store `clients_id` and `client_categories_id` into `clients_category_merge` table, as a single client can have multiple client categories.

How do I add the record to 2 tables (`clients` and `clients_category_merge`) when I only have one model (`clients`) when submitting the form?

I am sure there is a good way of doing this. But I am pretty new to Rails and lost on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `has_many :through` association will add the proper records for you.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_categories_merges
  has_many :client_categories, :through => :clients_categories_merges
end

class ClientCategories < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_categories_merges
  has_many :clients, :through => :clients_categories_merges
end

class ClientCategoryMerges < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_category
  belongs_to :client
end
```

[Check out this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

**Edit**: And [this one](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/)  for the corresponding forms

Comment: Thanks Luke! I had a look at your example & the guide, it's very good! But one more question: How do I specify category records in the customer form? Can I just loop through all the categories, set check-boxes and expect Rails to do the rest for me? :)

Comment: Added another link that should answer your question.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the last link! Totally answered my question! :D